# Android use different versions of Same JAR files based on Android OS Version

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have two sets of the same jar files with different versions (**1.0 and 1.1**). One set of Jars **(1.0)** will be working fine with Older Android versions **(Android 5.0 to Android 10)** and won't be working with **Android 11**. Similarly, another set of jars **(1.1)** will be working fine with newer Android versions **(Android 6.0 to Android 11)** and won't be working with **Android 5.0**. So, I need to use both jars and need to load corresponding jar files inside the libs folder based on the Android OS version. Where do I need to do the configuration something like inside build.gradle.

I thought to put two sets of jar files inside our app directory (Asset folder) and copy the corresponding jars inside the libs folder based on the OS version check.

Another approach is to make something like **build flavors**, but need some idea on how to do that.

Worst case maintaining two separate branches for two different versions.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: "I thought to put two sets of jar files inside our app directory (Asset folder) and copy the corresponding jars inside the libs folder based on the OS version check" -- the `libs/` directory is on your development machine, not the device. Also, this approach might violate your app distribution channel's terms of service (e.g., Play Store).

Comment: @CommonsWare So what would be your thought on this? Is there any optimal solution for this problem. Can we go with the build flavor approach? or any other lead for this problem.

Comment: "Is there any optimal solution for this problem" -- drop the seven-year-old Android 5.0.  "Can we go with the build flavor approach?" -- yes, but it would require you to go through extra work in app distribution, as you now need to distribute two editions of the app. You could look into using [`jarjar`](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) to revise one set of JARs to use a separate Java package. Then, you could link to both sets of JARs at once, and make a choice of which classes to use at runtime.